# Facebook widget working for some url but not for others

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Take a look at this fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVBQz/1/)

As you can see I have put up the facebook like box with url http://facebook.com/ElizaDoolittle

The problem is that it doesnt work with all urls, try replacing the url with this url: http://www.facebook.com/fatme.safa.3?ref=fs

you will see an error notification. Why is that?? What makes the difference in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see I have put up the facebook like box with url http://facebook.com/ElizaDoolittle

That is the address of a Facebook *page* for a musician.

> The problem is that it doesnt work with all urls, try replacing the url with this url: http://www.facebook.com/fatme.safa.3?ref=fs

That is the address of a *user profile*.

> you will see an error notification. Why is that?

Because only pages can be liked, user profiles **can not** be liked. And since, the Like box also does not work for user profiles.

Comment: Well that explains everything:)